# PHPUnit Code Coverage on multi-line parameter list

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have a constructor that looks something like this:

```
public function __construct(
    PusherManager $pusher,
    ParsePush $parse,
    PusherChannelNameCreator $channelNameCreator,
    ConversationOfferRepositoryInterface $offerRepository,
    ConversationOfferLogRepositoryInterface $offerLogRepository,
    ParseChannelNameCreator $parseChannelNameCreator,
    UserStatusService $userStatusService,
    UserSerializer $userSerializer,
    VisitorSerializer $visitorSerializer
) {
    $this->pusher = $pusher;
    $this->parse = $parse;
    $this->channelNameCreator = $channelNameCreator;
    $this->offerRepository = $offerRepository;
    $this->offerLogRepository = $offerLogRepository;
    $this->parseChannelNameCreator = $parseChannelNameCreator;
    $this->userStatusService = $userStatusService;
    $this->userSerializer = $userSerializer;
    $this->visitorSerializer = $visitorSerializer;
}
```

When I run PHPUnit code coverage on this file, it marks all of the lines between     `__construct(....)` as not covered, and it causes the percentage of lines covered result to be wrong.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please check the PHPUnit version you're using when running into this issue and add the version to your question.

Comment: @hakre I got a similar problem and I'm running PHPUnit 4.6.10 and Xdebug v2.5.5